# Fastest way to check for absolute bound

Tags: arm

In a function, I want to check the absolute bound of a number as a condition for an operation. I want to do `abs(r1) > 15` and right now I have an unoptimized way of doing it which is:

```
CMP    r1, #15
ADDGT  //operation
CMP    r1, #-15
ADDLT  //operation
```

Anyone thinks there could be a faster way? I was thinking of maybe right shifting by 4 so if it is less than +/-15, it will be all 1s or all 0s but I couldn't find a good way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this in fewer instructions and fewer conditional jumps, and good C-compilers will optimize `if (x > 15 || x < -15)` automatically. Hint: ARM is a two's complement machine.

Comment: I used https://gcc.godbolt.org/ to check and you were right, it helps save one instruction on the 4

`ADD   r3, r1, #15`
`CMP   r3, #30`
`ADDHI   //operation`

Thanks